# TextView is too small in tablet

Tags: android, layout

I've already created the layout-sw720dp but I don't know if I have to change all of the sizes of those Layouts,I mean I have layout-sw330dp, layout-sw480dp, and so on, I have to change the size of `TextView`, `Button`, and all of the stuff on the layout?

Is there any option to make it dynamic instead of changing it manually?

### Edit

My problem is when I run my app on a Nexus5 for instance it looks good, all size is correct, but when I try to run my app on Nexus9 all of the widgets are smalls (buttons, textviews, etc...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem - could you give a small example?

Comment: @0X0nosugar edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The recent update to [TextViews in support library v26](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) was built for just this purpose:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
      app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
      app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Edited my question